# how to perform undo operation into paints in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

hi i need perform undo operation in paints.some one suggest use command pattern  but i am not getting command pattern.is there any solution is there. help me how to do undo.
          i draw paints using below code.

```
         BookType3.class:
                 public class BookType3 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
          MyView  myview;
        int counter=0;
      private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
           TextView t1,t2;
           private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    public static boolean action=false;
       Button back,erase,undo,save,home;
      int image1,image2,image3;
         private Canvas  mCanvas;
         RelativeLayout relative;
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp6,lp7;
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                 setContentView(R.layout.booktype1);
          List<String> names = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
              relative=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative3);
               myview = new MyView(this);
                  myview.setId(004);
              lp6 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              myview.setLayoutParams(lp6);
             myview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.writingsapce);
              undo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.undobutton);
              undo.setOnClickListener(this);
                    mPaint = new Paint();
                   mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                 mPaint.setDither(true);
          mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
              mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
           mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
               mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
             String s1="";
         t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       t1.setOnClickListener(this);        
       t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.button2);
       t2.setOnClickListener(this);
           relative.addView(myview,lp6);
         }
           private Paint       mPaint;
            public class MyView extends View{
    private Path    mPath;
       public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }
            @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

      @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
                        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); 
                         if(action)
                              {
                        invalidate();

                          }
                          }

      private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 2;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            Log.i("x",""+event.getX());
            Log.i("y",""+event.getY());
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);

                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }


    }
     public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(v==t1)
{
     mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    t30.setText("A");
    t31.setText("a");
    t32.setText("Aa");
    t30.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    t31.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    t32.setTextColor(Color.RED);
       try{
        mBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
        Canvas Canvas=new Canvas(mBitmap);

        action=true;
    myview.onDraw(Canvas);

        }catch(IllegalStateException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(v==t2)
      {
    t30.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    t31.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    t32.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
     mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    t30.setText("B");
    t31.setText("b");
    t32.setText("Bb");
    try{
            mBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
            Canvas Canvas=new Canvas(mBitmap);
                   action=true;
        myview.onDraw(Canvas);

            }catch(IllegalStateException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
                      }
                                  if(v==undo)
                           {

                  }
                           }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Command Pattern, I think you should use the [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern), which is designed for things like undo and redo. There are two ways to implement this pattern. Either by saving deltas, or by saving entire states. Saving states would be easiest in your situation, but it has larger memory footprint. This would involve writing a bitmap to the filesystem every time the user modifies the main bitmap. You could decide on a constant number of undo steps (e.g. 10), and then save the 10 most recent bitmaps. Saving deltas would be more complex. You would implement it by recording the touch events, color, brush, etc. of each paint action. You can then playback and/or rollback individual actions using the motion events. Saving deltas would take significantly less memory, and you would be able to store many more actions and you wouldn't have to write to the filesystem.

Comment: The delta system you've described is basically what I thought of when I heard "command pattern." The commands would encode the action as well as expose both an execution and reversal method.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Slate mSlate;
private TiledBitmapCanvas mTiledCanvas;

 public void clickUndo(View unused) {

        mSlate.undo();
    }


public void undo() {
        if (mTiledCanvas == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "undo before mTiledCanvas inited");
        }
        mTiledCanvas.step(-1);

        invalidate();
    }
```